# Single- and double-check lazy initialization

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, lazy-initialization

I can't understand piece of code in Item 71 in 'Effective Java' about the Double-check idiom and the single-check idiom for lazy initialization of instance fields:

*Double-check idiom*

```
private volatile FieldType field;
FieldType getField() {
  FieldType result = field;
  if (result == null) {
    synchronized(this) {
      result == field;
      if (result == null)
        field = result = computeFieldValue();
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

*Single-check idiom*

```
private volatile FieldType field;
FieldType getField() {
  FieldType result = field;
  if (result == null) {
    field = result = computeFieldValue();
  }
  return result;
}
```

We use locking in first case, as i understand, in order to `compute FieldValue()` performed atomically. But why we omit it in second case? Because now some alien thread could corrupt some value that take part in computation. What i missed?

Comment: Line 6 in the above example should be result = field; not ==, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point of double-checked locking is that it ensures that `computeFieldValue` is invoked only once, and the field written to only once.

There are cases where it is acceptable to call this method more than once, making double-checked locking an overkill. These are some of the conditions to meet:

- `computeFieldValue` should be a *pure function*, always returning the same value;
- the magnitude of the risk of it being called more than once is acceptable (chances of that happening multiplied by its performance impact).